# How to change background across all activities?

Tags: java, android, background-image, android-mediaplayer, menuitem

**This is my code that changes the background**

```java
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.theme1:
            mainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blackgreygradientbackground);
            if (selectedBackgroundId == R.id.theme1){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Background already set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Background set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            selectedBackgroundId = R.id.theme1;
            return true;

        case R.id.theme2:
            mainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redpinkgradientbackground);
            if (selectedBackgroundId == R.id.theme2){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Background already set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Background set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            selectedBackgroundId = R.id.theme2;
            return true;
     }
 }
```

In my mainactivity the user can change the background in the toolbar by clicking on the menu and it does change the background, but the problem is how can i change it across all activities and save it when the user closes the app and restarts it?

So my problems are:

1. Now it only changes the background for the mainactivity, but i want to achieve that is changes across all my activities.
2. How can i save the picked background on restart?

Im using my own images as background and could only find tutorials with colors.

Thanks in advance,

Vince

**Edit**

```
   int theme1 = R.drawable.blackgreygradientbackground;
   int theme2 = R.drawable.redpinkgradientbackground;
   int mSelectedBackground;

   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.theme1:
            mainLayout.setBackgroundResource(theme1);
            mSelectedBackground = theme1;
            mEditor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
            mEditor.putInt("mSelectedBackground", mSelectedBackground);
            mEditor.apply();
            if (selectedBackgroundId == R.id.theme1){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Background already set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Background set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            selectedBackgroundId = R.id.theme1;
            return true;
        case R.id.theme2:
            mainLayout.setBackgroundResource(theme2);
            mSelectedBackground = theme2;
            mEditor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
            mEditor.putInt("mSelectedBackground", mSelectedBackground);
            mEditor.apply();
            if (selectedBackgroundId == R.id.theme2){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Background already set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Background set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            selectedBackgroundId = R.id.theme2;
            return true;

      }
 }
```

So i'm not sure if i'm doing it right, i followed the documentation but how can i now set the mainlayout of my activity to the user picked background across all activities and save it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the selected background in a persistent storage(like SharedPreferences)

And on onCreate of each of your activity you can set it by fetching from the save SharedPreferences

Example can be found here:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: You have save the background in preference.. Now load it in other activities oncreate